# Set Value of Cell, relative to active cell, within single column named range

Tags: vba, excel, function, named-parameters

I have written the following code as part of a larger sub-routine to set the value of a cell, relative to the active cell, when a particular selection has been made within the active cell.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "CLV 7"
```

While this works, I may have need in the future to add columns into my worksheet and this presents a problem, due to the change of location of the cell that requires its value to be set, and by association the need to rewrite the code each time a new column is added.

In considering this variable, I researched and as a result, defined a range name for each column that requires values to be set within it.  I thought that I would then be able to determine the variable & relocatable intersect point between the active row and the named range column and define it as the cell that requires the value to be set.

After this I researched ways to define this variable intersection and attempted to set the following alternate code:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Range("BusinessStudies").Value = CLV 7
```

in the hope that it would do the trick, but unfortunately it does not.  I have looked at other posts and cannot see how to adjust it with any success as I can't see any similar requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the Intersect() function in VBA

```
Debug.Print Intersect(Rows(ActiveCell.Row), Range("MyRange")).Value
```

Edit: apply to your situation, assuming that you want the string "CLV 7" to go into the cell:

```
Intersect(Rows(ActiveCell.Row), Range("BusinessStudies")).Value = "CLV 7"
```

Comment: Thanks @teylyn.  I assume that this requires a definition of "MyRange"? I think I have seen that this requires some code to do so earlier in the sub routine but I am not confident about that.  Could you please point me in the right direction so that I can complete that part as well?

Comment: In thinking it through further, is it that 'MyRange' is replaced with the range name already defined?  Also, do I simply use this code to replace the current code and add ' = "CLV 7" at the end?  So the new code would look like this:

    Debug.Print Intersect(Rows(ActiveCell.Row), Range("BusinessStudies")).Value = "CLV7"

Edit:  I tried this just now and it doesn't work.  Could you suggest any other adjustments or alternatives?

Comment: Yes. You can easily apply this to your situation. `Intersect(Rows(ActiveCell.Row), Range("BusinessStudies")).Value = "whatever"`. You would need to replace "whatever" with whatever you want in the cell. I edited my post.

Comment: You little ripper (Not sure where you're from but if not from Australia that's Aussie Slang for That works beautifully - Thanks heaps!).  The perfect and most simple solution!

Comment: Kiwi. Thanks for the feedback.